# How to access a certain value in an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array called `someArray`. I would like to access the name value of the `NSArray`. I'm trying to access it using the following, but with out any luck. How do I do it properly?

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

some array {
    haserror = 0;
    headers =     {
        code = 0;
        haserror = 0;
        nodeid = "fe1.aaaaaa.2.undefined";
        time = 16;
    };
    results =     (
                {
            coords =             (
                "44.916667",
                "8.616667"
            );
            id = 2;
            key = alessandria;
            name = Alessandria;
            state = Piemonte;
            zip = 1512;
        },
                {
            coords =             (
                "43.616944",
                "13.516667"
            );
            id = 3;
            key = ancona;
            name = Ancona;
            state = Marche;
            zip = 601;
        },

}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: whats the problem you facing?

Comment: Are sure that `someArray` is an array, because if he output looks like a `NSDictionary` with an array for the item `results`.

Comment: Post your error messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, `someArray` is a dictionary while `results` is a key pointing to an array inside of your dictionary. If you want an array of all of the name fields in your `results` array, you could use `valueForKeyPath:` on the `someArray` variable, like this:

```
NSArray *names = [someArray valueForKeyPath:@"results.name"];
```

The `names` variable should now contain "Alessandria", and "Ancona" from the data set your show in your example code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i see from you data model, the key `name` is a node under the key `results`. You can use this data model as a dictionary map, the code snippet below must give you what you need..

```
NSDictionary *myObject = [[someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"results"];
cell.textLabel.text = [myObject objectForKey:"name"];
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** *If you have some lopps or some other mechanisms for receiving data, there may be more efficent ways for your sıolution, so please give some more additional info about what you are exactly tryin to do*

Comment: I think you may have the first line backwards. "someArray" looks to be a dict, and "results" is the array.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I assumed the array as a dictionary(since it is a part of dictionary). I reviewed again and i think this code must run, if i'm wrong, please let me know.